# How to include sitemap.xml in the build of a react+vite project

Tags: reactjs, build, vite, sitemap, google-search

I have a react+vite project, which I wish to index in google search.

So, I created a sitemap.xml file and included it in the public folder of my root directory.

How do I make this sitemap.xml file appear in the build folder when I deploy on github pages or on netlify

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4O0L.png)

Comment: when you run manually `npm build`, does the sitemap.xml file not appear in the `build` folder? Because it should, and so you don't really have to do anything as long as you have included the file in the `public` folder.

Comment: @Airah no, it does not appear.